# mysql_fetch_assoc() only works for one iteration in WHILE loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, fetch

Please consider the following:

```
$query = "SELECT legIDs FROM trip";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SELECT TRIPS ERROR: " . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die("fetch error " . mysql_error())) {
    echo "<div style=\"border: 1px solid blue;float:left;\">Trip: <div style=\"float:right;\">";
    $legID = explode(",", $row['legIDs']);
        foreach($legID as $leg) {
            $query = "SELECT dep, arr FROM leg WHERE `Key` = " . $leg;
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("SELECT LEGS ERROR: " . mysql_error());
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die("FILL ARRAY ERROR: " . mysql_error());
            echo $row2['dep'] . " - " . $row2['arr'] . "<br />";
    }
    echo "</div></div>";
}
```

For some reason this only returns one result, even when there are several values returned from the `WHILE()` loop. The `FOREACH()` loop works on the one row that's returned. Am I doing something wrong to only have this return one row? Performing the query contained in `$result` directly on the server returns several rows.

Comment: `The FOREACH() loop works on the one row that's returned.` - Actually no, it doesn't. You're never using `$row`. May that be the bug?

Comment: Your sequence is a little odd. You're fetching from $result before you've queried. Normally you do your query first, then fetch from the results in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, removed a line from my question that didn't seem relevant. `$row` is used in the following line: `$legID = explode(",", $row['legIDs']);` which appears immediately before the `FOREACH()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `$result` twice in the inner and outer loops.. When the inner loop completes, $result will be an "empty" result set, so the outer loop will terminate. CHange the inner loop to `$result2` and things should be fine.

However, since the inner loop is simply fetching more results based on what the outer loop produces, you should consider rewriting it as a joined query. It's almost always more efficient to run a single "large result" query, than a long series of "small result" individual queries. You end up with fairly hefty overhead to parse/compile each of the inner queries.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I think this is part of the problem. Can you also please expand on how that could be combined into one query? I realize I need to keep queries to a minimum but one result from the query to the `trip` table may correspond to multiple results from the `leg` table.

Comment: @Chris: I was happily writing you a combined query when I realized that you're storing multiple values in one field. That should be separated out into another table.... otherwise queries like this become a nightmare.

Comment: I ended up changing all the variables used twice (don't know how I didn't think of that in the first place!) and it got rid of the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: given your two queries, something like `select trip.legIDs, leg.dep, leg.arr FROM trip JOIN leg ON trip.legIDs = leg.Key` would do the trick. Then you get all three values in a single query. Some simple state checking to check which legIDs you're on to output a new `<div>` when it changes, and you should be good to go.

Comment: This issue was hard to notice. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite messy stuff there.

1. `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die("FETCH ERROR: " . mysql_error()))`

   There's no need for the `or die()`. If `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `false`, the `while` loop is supposed to end, you don't need to `die` as well.
2. SQL queries within loops based on other SQL queries are usually better handled via better JOINs in the original query or by making more intelligent secondary queries.
3. You're overwriting your `$result` variable of the outer loop in the inner loop, which is probably the cause for the particular problem you're asking about.
4. You should separate data fetching from outputting. Do your queries first to fetch all necessary data, then output it into `<div>`s. Mixing presentation logic and backend logic gets very messy very quickly.

Comment: to extend on (1) you'd typically write
`while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))!==false) { ... }`